# async file upload does not prompt browser to download file

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I have created an async file download method that doesn't prompt the user to download the file. There are no errors, the code and the jquery runs fine, however, the browser doesn't prompt a download. I have looked at all the solutions on SO but mine seems to not work.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method(string data)
{
    //do stuff

     response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
     response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(downloadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");                        
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = myFileName;
     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

      return response;

}
```

Comment: What is this piece of code `{FileName = myFileName};` doing in the middle of your other `response` field setting code?

Comment: didn't realize I was setting FileName twice. Removed it in the edit but that has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: putting an iframe on the page solved the issue but there's got to be another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an iframe and changing its source after the $.get is completed got the browser to open the download dialog.

```
function callback(result) {

                $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/worksitefileservice/api/xfer/download?data=' + encodeURIComponent(json));
            }

<iframe id="myFrame" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" src=""></iframe>
```